# Do savestate before power off host (Virtualbox/OpenSUSE)

Tags: opensuse, virtualbox

I was working on a old version of VirtualBox (3.2.6) in which I can edit `/etc/sysconfig/vbox`, there I can add as many VM to start when the host boots up.

Now on the this new version 4.2.6 can't edit that file because [it's no longer supported](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#autostart). Checking [on the forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=51548#p236113) I found something but I does not work.

```
cat /etc/default/virtualbox
# /etc/default/virtualbox
#
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# In the "SHUTDOWN_USERS" list all users for which a check for runnings VMs should be done during
# shutdown of "vboxdrv" resp. the server:
# SHUTDOWN_USERS="foo bar"
#
# Set "SHUTDOWN" to one of "poweroff", "acpibutton" or "savestate" depending on which of the
# shutdown methods for running VMs are wanted:
# SHUTDOWN="poweroff"
# SHUTDOWN="acpibutton"
# SHUTDOWN="savestate"
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#SHUTDOWN_USERS="foo bar"
#SHUTDOWN="savestate"
VBOXAUTOSTART_DB=/etc/vbox
#VBOXAUTOSTART_CONFIG=/etc/vbox/vbox.cfg
VBOXAUTOSTART_CONFIG=/etc/vbox/vboxauto.conf
```

this is `vboxauto.conf`:

```
cat /etc/vbox/vboxauto.conf
# Default policy is to deny starting a VM, the other option is "allow".
default_policy = deny

root = {
    allow = true
}
```

then I do this:

```
VBoxManage setproperty autostartdbpath /etc/vbox
```

and this

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <the_machine> --autostart-enabled on
```

when i try to look at the status

```
rcvboxes status
Virtualbox machines: no virtual machines running.                                                                                                                       skipped
vboxes.service - LSB: Autostart Virtual Box VMs
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vboxes)
          Active: active (exited) since Tue, 2013-02-05 23:34:57 UYST; 32min ago
         Process: 30764 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vboxes start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/vboxes.service

Feb 05 23:34:57 my.machine vboxes[30764]: Starting Virtualbox machines: no virtual machines configured..unused
Feb 05 23:34:57 my.machine systemd[1]: Started LSB: Autostart Virtual Box VMs.
```

why won't VirtualBox see my virtual machines to leave them headless?
**Edit 30 - may**

I did configure it in */etc/sysconfig/vbox*, but get this when I run it 
under init.d

```
/etc/init.d/vboxes status
Virtualbox machines: no virtual machines running.                    skipped
vboxes.service - LSB: Autostart Virtual Box VMs
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vboxes)
          Active: inactive (dead) since Sat, 2013-02-02 22:00:49 UYST; 1 day and 21h ago
         Process: 4155 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/vboxes stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 3955 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vboxes start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/vboxes.service
```

I did a small test and move the script to /root/bin an it worked just fine.

```
./vboxes_test status
 test (user: root):                                       running (since 2013-02-04 21:55:46)                                                        running
 test (user: root):                                       running (since 2013-02-04 21:55:46)
```

**small edit:**
So far this is what I was talking about.... anyway did the old configuration (add the vm in /etc/sysconfig/vbox) and **now then I reboot the host the vms also do that.** The thing is I don want the vms to reboot when I poweroff the host: t**he vms must do savestate before the host shutdown**.

**small_coment:**
If I previous do a savestate and the reboot the host.. the vms do work as I wanted...

Is there any info to make it work?

Comment: if you speak Spanish, please visit the opensuse forum http://www.forosuse.org/forosuse/showthread.php?p=162878#post162878

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the command you're looking for is this:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm <Machine Name> --autostop-type savestate
```

The following are alternatives to savestate: `[disabled|savestate|poweroff|acpishutdown]`.

If that doesn't work I believe you can use the `acpishutdown` option to configure the VM so that when it receives the trigger to `acpishutdown` to savestate as well.

If the above doesn't work there is always manually doing the savestates yourself using this command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm> savestate
```

And then rebooting the host system.

#### References

- [Installing VirtualBox on our Linux Clients](https://blogs.wellesley.edu/cssysadmin/2012/10/16/installing-virtualbox-on-our-linux-clients/)
- [How To Set Your VirtualBox 4.2 VM to Automatically Startup](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-to-set-your-virtualbox-vm-to-automatically-startup/)
- [Virtualbox 4.2 VM autostart on Debian Squeeze](http://codepoets.co.uk/2012/virtualbox-4-2-vm-autostart-on-debian-squeeze/)
- [Start VMs at boot (new in 4.2.0)](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=51529)

Comment: Actually I did all those things but get no good results. Maybe Is something on the OpenSuSe but not so sure... Really need some extra help.

Comment: maybe is something else that not works on opensuse... thanks anyway. Your answer looks right.

Comment: Thanks. I've researched this a lot and I can't find anything else other than the above to do. It should work so without more of your setup I can't really assist further. Sorry! Also with the bounties if you don't award them they go away. Do as you wish, just letting you know.